# databricks: reading from datawarehouse temp directory

Tags: data-warehouse, databricks

I am writing a function like the following

```
def fromdw():
  df=spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")\
  .option("url", myurl) \
  .option("query",sqlquery)\
  .option( "forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True")\
  .option("tempdir", mytempurl)\
  .load()
  return df
```

may I know the option tempdir is compulsory? i want to do a read without tempdir , because it was slow as it require to stage the results in a Blob folder first.

Comment: yes Michael temp dir is required to access your data. you can try like this `val df: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<the-rest-of-the-connection-string>")
  .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<your-container-name>@<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-directory-name>")
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("dbTable", "my_table_in_dw")
  .load() `

Comment: using jdbc does't need any temp dir

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use JDBC for smaller, faster queries.  Use the Databricks spark connector for SQL DW (Synape) for moving large data sets.  This connector bypasses both the Spark Driver node and the Synapse head node, and by using Azure Storage as a staging area, allows the unload and load to be performed in parallel by the clusters in either direction.

JDBC is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases#python-example), and looks like this:

```
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : user,
  "password" : pw,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

pushdown_query = "(select * from whatever) q"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

(notice how you have to wrap the SELECT to use a query instead of a table name).